# How to hispanicize (rather unknown) German toponyms with umlaut?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, símbolos, extranjerismos, transliteración

If one is interested in proper names in German, like *München* or *Zürich*, one easily knows the Spanish translation, and if not, one goes to Wikipedia and finds the translation. But what to do with unknown toponyms?

For instance, suppose one is interested in, say, the name in Spanish of a smaller city, Göppingen. "Luckily" there is [the page in Spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6ppingen) but the "translation" is somehow rare: For if *Göttingen* in Spanish is said *Gotinga*, why isn't *Göppingen* translated as *Gopinga*?

- Is there a rule to hispanicize German names with umlaut?
- If there is, provide it. If not, I guess the best thing to do is to use the German word. How to correctly read the umlaut on vowels that don't exist in our phonetics?
- What's the right thing to do, use an approximation or just pronounce it in German?

Comment: I assume it's a pretty tough challenge for Spanish speakers to "pronounce it in German", especially a sound that does not exist in their tongue. – However, I guess that it's the most favorable approach. Try to pronounce it, do your best ;)

Comment: @Em1 nö, darum geht's gar nicht :) I mean, even for you will be a little problem to say that in Spanish, 'cause the interlocutors should also do their part. And it sounds trivial, but what's the right convention? to say diphthongs for each *ö* and *ü* to be understandable doesn't sound like an elegant solution (even if it works).

Comment: Well, actually, I can't say if there's a convention in Spanish. I only know how I handle such a thing. Whenever I travel, I try to pronounce the places I visit as natives do. I will fail to pronounce them perfectly but I'm often close to. And when talking about villages in my home, I simply call them exactly as they are. There are just a few exceptions, like Munich, Berlin, Cologne, i.e. the biggest/famous cities.

Comment: Sixty years ago, in Chile or Argentina, it was very funny to listen to Germans trying to speak Spanish.  The same probably goes in reverse.

Answer (score 10):

Según el diccionario [panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-toponimos)

Resume en 6 partes la transcripción de topónimos.

> 1. Topónimos con forma tradicional plenamente vigente en español, que, no obstante, aparecen con cierta frecuencia en los medios de comunicación con nombres o grafías propios de otras lenguas. Se prefiere la forma española, a no ser que haya caído en desuso o se haya producido un cambio de denominación: Amberes (no Antwerpen ni Anvers), Ciudad del Cabo (no Cape Town), Milán (no Milano) o Nueva York (no New York).
> 2. Topónimos que carecen de forma adaptada al español y se emplean tradicionalmente con la grafía propia de la lengua local o con la grafía correspondiente a una lengua puente. Se respetan estas grafías, incluso en lo concerniente a su acentuación, por tratarse de formas ya asentadas en el uso: Canterbury, Ottawa, Washington o Copenhague (del inglés Copenhagen, en danés København).
> 3. Topónimos cuya forma tradicional en español ha caído en desuso en favor de la forma local. Se da primacía a la forma local: Ankara (antes Angora), Bremen (antes Brema) o Maastricht (antes Mastrique).
> 4. Topónimos con cambio de denominación oficial en favor de la forma local, pero que cuentan con una forma tradicional española plenamente vigente. Se prefiere la forma española: Calcuta (no Kolkata), Moldavia (no Moldova), Bombay (no Mumbai) o Esmirna (no Izmir). Solo en aquellos casos en que se ha producido un verdadero cambio de nombre (y no una mera reivindicación de las formas locales de este) se recomienda la nueva denominación, que debe sustituir a la anterior: Burkina Faso (antiguo Alto Volta) o Sri Lanka (antiguo Ceilán).
> 5. Topónimos que se emplean a menudo con grafías que responden a la transliteración o representación en otras lenguas (normalmente el inglés o el francés) del nombre local, perteneciente este, por lo general, a lenguas que utilizan alfabetos no latinos o que carecen de escritura. Se propone la adaptación de esas formas al sistema gráfico del español de acuerdo con la pronunciación más generalizada entre los hispanohablantes: Zimbabue (no Zimbabwe), Punyab (no Punjab) o Buriatia (no Buryatia).
> 6. En el caso de topónimos pertenecientes a lenguas que utilizan alfabetos no latinos, se recomienda la forma gráfica que resulta de aplicar las normas de transliteración de esos alfabetos al español y se reconocen, si las hay, otras grafías asentadas: Qatar o Iraq (también Irak). Las formas transcritas se acentúan gráficamente de acuerdo con las normas ortográficas del español: Shanghái, Taipéi. En cuanto a los topónimos que responden al estándar «pinyin», se prefiere, si la hay, la forma tradicional española: Pekín (no Beijing), Cantón (no Guangdong [provincia] ni Guangzhou [capital]) o Nankín (no Nanjing).

Ambas poblaciones parece que no se usarán en español y que hayan caído en desuso o de su desuso haya un cambio de denominación. En ingles se mantiene bajo el mismo nombre, no hay adaptación como el caso de Copenhagen, así en español también como dice Gorpik.

Comment: It is clear from this DPD quote that the RAE does not recommend adapting foreign names when they are originally written in the Latin alphabet, only to use adaptations when they exist and are in current use. Therefore, Göppingen should be written this way in Spanish. As for the pronunciation, I guess most Spanish speakers would pronounce *Gópinguen*.

Comment: ¿Usar de lengua puente el inglés? ¿Tiene el inglés más exónimos? Y si los tuviera, habría que hacer una segunda adaptación, lo cual me parece más confuso.

Comment: He visto que en inglés se conserva el nombre en la lengua local, he editado la respuesta. Lo de los exónimos era más que nada una opinión, no creo que sea ventajoso que hayan muchos para cada ciudad. En el caso de que en ingles fuera muy empleado no sería una segunda adaptación, sino como dice el apartado dos, utilizar el mismo nombre, aunque con el ejemplo de Copenhagen no se si es por la adaptación a su grafía ya que el símbolo ø no existe en inglés y se aprovecho que en castellano tampoco. Por cierto que vives allí? Veo en tu perfil que estas en Alemania ;)

Comment: El caso de Copenhague significa, simplemente, que el nombre de esa ciudad llegó a nosotros a través del inglés. Del mismo modo que el nombre de Moscú llegó a nosotros a través del francés (Moscou) y no directamente del ruso (Moskvá); el río del mismo nombre, en cambio, se llama en español Moscova porque se ha tomado posteriormente del original ruso. El uso de una lengua puente no se hace intencionadamente, sino que ha ocurrido por razones históricas.