# ¿Por qué Brujas se llama así y no "Puentes" si viene de Brugge que quiere decir "puente"?

Tags: etimología, historia, topónimos

La ciudad belga de [Brujas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brujas) se llama *Brugge* en flamenco. En la Wikipedia leemos que:

> Su nombre proviene del noruego antiguo "Bryggia" (puentes, muelles,
>   atracaderos). Es interesante destacar que en el idioma
>   flamenco/neerlandés «Brug» significa «puente», y que esta ciudad
>   ostenta como nombre el plural de esta palabra debido a la gran
>   cantidad de puentes que en ella existen.

Por lo que me pregunto: ¿por qué se eligió llamarla "Brujas" en castellano en lugar de "Puentes" que sería la traducción?

Lo mismo me sugieren los nombres de los siguientes lugares:

- Islandia. [Viene de](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islandia#Etimolog.C3.ADa) "tierra de hielo" y en inglés se llama de hecho *Iceland*. ¿Por qué no la llamamos algo así como *Hielolandia*?
- Groenlandia. [Viene de](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groenlandia#Etimolog.C3.ADa) "tierra (o país) verde" y en inglés se llama Greenland. ¿Por qué no la llamamos *Verdelandia*?

En general, ¿cuál es el proceso por el que se traduce un nombre de localidad -ie, pasar a decir "Brujas" en lugar del original "Brugge"- y cuál es la metodología utilizada para adaptarlo a nuestra lengua?

Comment: ¿O bien porqué tampoco decimos por *Islandia* alguna palabra más parecida a *Tierrahelada* o *Tierra de Hielo(s)*, sabes? Temo que todo esto sea algo perdido en la antigüedad de la lengua y en tradiciones olvidadas, pero quizás tenga alguien otra explicación mejor.

Comment: Es que *Brujas* no es una traducción sino una adaptación fonética, de las cuales hay multitud de ejemplos en todos los idiomas.

Comment: Lo bueno sería escribir y pronunciar los lugares como lo llaman los lugareños, ya que ahora es más fácil aprender por medio de internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El proceso de adaptación de un nombre no es único y depende mucho de la época en que se ha hecho. Sobre todo, ten en cuenta que los exónimos se generan con el uso, no se siguen reglas ni hay una persona que los imponga.

Brujas está en Flandes, que era una posesión de la corona española en los siglos XVI y XVII; por tanto, esa adaptación se realizó en aquella época, igual que la de muchas otras ciudades flamencas como Lieja o Amberes. En esa época, lo normal era que el nombre original se convirtiera en algo parecido, pero fácil de pronunciar para un castellanoparlante. Si había una palabra parecida en español, era fácil que se asimilara. De ahí *Brugge* -> *Brujas*.

Otro nombre geográfico que en español se asimiló a una palabra existente con sonido similar en lugar de a la traducción del original es el *Canal de la Mancha* (del francés *Canal de la Manche*, canal de la Manga). La Mancha es una comarca española que, desde luego, no tiene nada que ver con el canal, pero el nombre se asimiló.

Una asimilación curiosa es la de la capital de Rusia, cuyo nombre ruso es *Moskvá*, igual al del río que la atraviesa. En castellano, el nombre de la ciudad es *Moscú*, formado al escribir con la ortografía española el francés *Moscou*; sin embargo, el del río es *Moscova*, convirtiendo el nombre original ruso en algo fácilmente pronunciable para un hispanohablante. ¿Por qué el mismo nombre ha dado en español dos distintos? Porque se han asimilado en momentos distintos y por personas distintas. No hay reglas fijas.

Comment: Añado la respuesta dada en otro *post*, la pregunta no es la misma pero la respuesta es útil y proviene de la RAE, aquí se define el proceso para adaptar topónimos a nuestra lengua.

http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/how-to-hispanizise-rather-unknown-german-toponyms-with-umlaut?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Muy buena la respuesta.  Tal vez otro ejemplo de asimilación sería el estado de Texas en los EEUU.  La pronunciación de la equis es diferente en inglés de lo que es en español.  Claro que este ejemplo es in dirección contraria, y tal vez no viene al grano.

Comment: @AlexBcn Vaya, no recordaba mi comentario a esa respuesta y resulta que pongo el mismo ejemplo que aquí :D Sí, la pregunta no es la misma, pero tu respuesta a la otra es bastante pertinente.

Comment: @WalterMitty Tal vez más parecido al caso de Brujas sea el de *Key West*, en español *Cayo Hueso*. Al parecer, el nombre inglés procede del español por similitud fonética, aunque también influido por el hecho de ser el más occidental de los cayos de Florida.

Comment: O tal vez cayo largo, que sería "long key" en vez de "key largo".

Comment: Y ni hablemos de llamar la cárcel "hoosegow", que creo que viene de "juzgado".

Answer (score 3):

Iceland viene de una palabra islandés que quiere decir "isla".  No tiene nada que ver con hielo.  Esto es según el diccionario Merriam Webster.  La entrada para [Iceland](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iceland) tiene unos botones donde se puede escuchar la palabra en inglés, en danés, y en islandés.  Se puede notar que la palabra en islandés se escribe igual que la palabra en inglés "island", salvo que la ese in inglés es muda.

No estoy de acuerdo con la tradición que dice que viene del noruego, y quiere decir tierra de hielo.

Se me hace que en la mayoría de los casos, el nombre de un sitio en otro idioma viene del sonido y no del significado.  Algo semejante debe ser la explicación de la conección entre "Bruges" y "Brujas".

Comment: ¡Interesante! Pero bueno, era un ejemplo. De todos modos, leo en [la Wik](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islandia#Etimolog.C3.ADa)i _La palabra «Islandia» deriva del islandés Ísland, vocablo que proviene del nórdico antiguo, que significa «tierra de hielo»_ También veo en [How did Iceland get its name?](http://icelandreview.com/stuff/ask-ir/2013/04/20/how-did-iceland-get-its-name) que _in many other languages, like French and German, the name for Iceland doesn’t have anything to do with ice and cold but is called Islande and Island (as opposed to Pays de Glace and Eisland)._